# How to extrude mesh?

Tags: c#

Say we have the following simple mesh data:

```
// additional data
// Vector3(x, y, z) - +x left, +y up, +z forward
// triangle indices are in clocwise order

// list of vertices that form a place
List<Vector3> vertices = new List<Vector3>() {
  new Vector3(2f, 0f, 2f),
  new Vector3(-2f, 0f, 2f),
  new Vector3(2f, 0f, -2f),
  new Vector3(-2f, 0f, -2f),
};

List<int> indices = new List<int>() {
  0, 3, 2, 3, 0, 1
};
```

How to extrude given plane in a certain direction? E.g `2f` in `y` axis, it should form a bottomless cube.

I'm interested in how it works in general, not only this specific example.

Comment: What is the variable `indices`?

Comment: Array of triangle indexes, each 3 numbers form a triangle. Number is the index of vertex in vertices array, i.e 3 is fourth vertex (array begins from a 0).